# Nginx auth_basic and rewrite in subdirectory does not work

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to add a project to a subfolder of existing webserver with Nginx. Here's my simple config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www;

        [...]

    location = /my-project { return 301 /my-project/; }
    location /my-project/ {
        alias /var/www/my-project/web/;
        index index.php;
        location ~ /[^/]+/control(/|$) {
            auth_basic            "Restricted";
            auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
            if (-f $request_filename) { break; }
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /my-project/index.php last;
        }
        if (-f $request_filename) { break; }
        rewrite ^ /my-project/index.php last;
        location ~ ^/[^/]+/index\.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgi.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        }
    }
}
```

Because there is an rewrite directive inside `/control` location block, the `auth_basic` never gets triggered, because Nginx executes rewrites before authentication. In which way should I modify the config, that auth does work?

PS: `try_files` doesn't seem to work, because it serves files from root (/) webfolder!? When I replace the `if` and following `rewrite` with `try_files $uri /my-project/index.php?$query_string;` I get a 404, because Nginx tries to serve the file `/var/wwwindex.php` (have a look at missing slash and the root folder `/var/www` instead of alias).

**EDIT 18.09.2013:**
As VBart suggests I'm using now the following configuration to get authentication to work

```
location ~ ^/(?<dir>my-project)(?<path>/.*)$ {
    root /var/www/$dir/web;
    location ~ ^/[^/]+/control(/|$) {
        auth_basic            "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
        try_files $path /$dir/index.php?$query_string;
    }
    try_files $path /$dir/index.php?$query_string;
    location ~ ^/[^/]+/index\.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgi.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/index.php;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
error_page 404 =200 /my-project/index.php;
```

instead of ugly rewrites:

```
if (-f $request_filename) { break; }
rewrite ^(.*)$ /my-project/index.php last;
```

Reference:

- http://nginx.org/r/error_page
- http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil
- http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls

P.S. `try_files` doesn't work with `alias` because of bug: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97, but you can replace `alias` with `root` directive: http://nginx.org/r/root

Comment: And you don't need to declare it twice, since it is inherited. You can configure `error_page` once in outer `location` block.

Comment: Please help again, as I can see, there are no POSTs possible anymore? (So no login form, no registration form... are working) I think `error_page` cannot work with POST requests. So this would not fit me requirements :(

Comment: Then use `try_files` with the `root` directive instead of `alias`.

Comment: Using `try_files` with `root` results in 404 for static files. Debug log gives `http uri: "/my-project/js/main.js"` and fails on `trying to use file: "/my-project/js/main.js" "/var/www/my-project/web/my-project/js/main.js"` because Nginx uses full URI to look for file in directory `.../web` and not only `/js/main.js`

Comment: In this case you should modify your `location` to capture only part of URI, like this: `location ~^/my-project(?<path>/.*)$ { try_files $path /my-project/index.php?$query_string; }`

Comment: Have a look at my edited question. Although, it's a bit to much regex for me (I think a `location` containing regular expressions costs performance). But it seems that this is the only way to get `try_files` to work.